# Understanding an unexpected result due to an unmatched prototype (C89)

Tags: c, prototype, c89

I have a program goo.c

```
void foo(double);

#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int x){
  printf ("in foo.c:: x= %d\n",x);
}
```

which is called by foo.c

```
int main(){
  double x=3.0;
  foo(x);
}
```

I compile and run

```
 gcc foo.c goo.c 
 ./a.out
```

Guess what? I get "x= 1" as result.  Then I find the signature of 'foo' should have been `void foo(int)`. Apparently, my double input value 3.0 has to be downcast to an int. But,  if I try to see the value of (int) 3.0 with the test program:

```
int main(){
  double x=3.0;
  printf ("%d", ((int) x));
}
```

I get 3 as output, which makes the earlier ` x= 1'  even more  hard to understand. Any idea? For information, my gcc is run with ANSI C standard. Thanks.

[EDIT] If I use gcc -S as suggested by JS1,

I get goo.s

```
.file   "goo.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movabsq $4613937818241073152, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm0
    call    foo
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

and foo.s

```
    .file   "foo.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "in foo.c:: x= %d\n"
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Anyone who knows how to read Assembly can help figure out the source problem?

Comment: What type of machine are you running on? Most likely, what happened is that doubles are passed to functions using floating point registers (as opposed to general purpose registers which are used for integers).  The function tries to read from the integer register which is uninitialized and just happens to be holding a 1.  You can see exactly what is happening if you use `-S` and look at the assembly code for your functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding why you get '1' requires a bit of ASM and x86-64 ABI
knowledge. First of all, `goo.c` and `foo.c` are two separate compilation
units. The only thing that `foo.c` knows about the `foo` function is
the bogus prototype.

The bogus prototype is as follows: `void foo(double);`. It's a function
that takes only a single double argument. The x86-64 ABI mandates that
the doubles are passed through the `xmm` registers (The exact phrasing
is 'If the class is SSE, the next available vector register is used,
the registers are taken in the order from %xmm0 to %xmm7.'.

That means that when the compiler sets up the arguments to call the
`foo()` function, it's going to pass the argument via `%xmm0`. In
simplified asm what happens is:

```
mov 3.0, %xmm0
call foo
```

Now, `foo()`, on it's side, believes it's going to recieve an int. The
x86-64 ABI says: 'If the class is INTEGER, the next available register
of the sequence %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used.'. The first
argument is supposed to be passed via `%rdi`. That means that `foo()`
will do something like:

```
mov %rdi, %rsi
mov 0xabcd, %rdi // 0xabcd being the address of the "%d" string
call printf
```

So you're going to end up printing whatever was in `%rsi`, and not `%xmm0`.

But why `1`? You'll get an idea by issuing the following commands:
    `./a.out a`
    `./a.out a b`
    `./a.out a b c`

See a pattern? Let's go back to the simplified assembly:

```
main:
    mov 3.0, %xmm0
    call foo
    ret

foo:
    mov %rdi, %rsi
    mov 0xabcd, %rdi // 0xabcd being the address of the "%d" string
    call printf
    ret
```

As you can see, nothing is setting `%rdi` until it reaches `foo()`,
where it's passed on to printf. Which means `1` was passed to `main`
in the first place. Now, in the question, `main` is given the following
prototype: `int main()`. But the compiler actually setup the function to
have the following prototype instead: `int main (int argc, char *argv[],
char *envp[])`. The first argument, thus stored in `%rdi`, is actually
`argc`. That's why the program was printing `1`.

Comment: Wow! A great explanation. Thanks so much for the detailed, informative answer.  I have just pasted the .s files for your reference.

Comment: My pleasure. You might enjoy this presentation. It covers similar problems: http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c